# Nodejs request patch

Tags: node.js, promise, request, patch

I'm currently trying to implement a patch request in my nodejs application. But I can't seem to get it to work. I have made sure my data structure is correct.

I've tried some different things like: returning my request.patch and promise but nothing seem to happen.

```
var request = require('request');
exports.patchOwner = function (options) {
    var urlEncodedParams = encodeURI(options.nodeId);
    request.patch(url + '/owner/owners/' + urlEncodedParams, JSON.stringify(options.body), function (err, res, body) {
            //body is empty
    });
```

}

Comment: Is `err` empty too ?

Comment: yes, and I have also made sure I can patch through tools like postman

Comment: Ok, and what does `res` look like ?

Comment: It is null ----

Comment: and what should `body` or `res` return ? maybe you server returns nothing but `err` on a `patch` regular call

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var fullUrl = url + '/owner/owners/' + encodeURI(options.nodeId);
var body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
request.patch({ url: fullUrl, body: body }, function (err, res, body) {
  // do your thing
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Express for `patch` request

**server.js**

```
app.patch("/data/:id/:patch", (q, r) => {
    let id=q.params.id;
    let id=q.params.patch;

    //your logic

    r.send({ res: "*PATCHED*" });
});
```

**client.js**

```
let ajax = (type, url, data, callback) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(/* GET */type, url, true/* ASYNC */);
    xhr.onload = () => callback(xhr.status === 200 ? JSON.parse(xhr.response).res : xhr.status);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if (type === "POST")
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    else
        xhr.send();//PUT - PATCH - DELETE - GET
}
```

**usage**

```
ajax('PATCH', '/data/1/something_to_patch', null, (res)=>{alert(res)});
```

same logic for `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

but for `POST`:

**server.js**

```
app.post("/data", (q, r) => {
    let body_data = JSON.stringify(q.body);
    r.send({ res: "*POST: " + body_data + "*" });
});
```

**client; post data with js:**

```
<script>
    let data = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "AJAX_POST"
    }

    ajax('POST', '/data', data, (res)=>{alert(res)});
</script>
```

**client; post form:**

```
<form action="/data" method="POST">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input name="name" type="hidden" value="FORM_POST" />
    <input type="submit" value="FORM_POST" />
</form>
```